# Find a number that occurs twice in an array

Tags: c, arrays, repeat

I have to write a program where the user enters a number *n*, and then enters *n*+1 numbers in the range [1, n], where exactly one of those numbers occurs more than once. The program returns the number that occurs more than once.

So, for example, if the input is like this:

```
3
1
2
3
2
```

then *n* = 3, the rest of the input is four numbers in the range [1,3], and the output is `2` (since that's the number that occurs more than once).

I am not allowed to use vectors.

I thought I could do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i,n,nr,x,num,aux,k;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    nr = 0;
    for (i=0; i < n+1; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        nr = nr * 10 + num; 
    }
    k=1;
    while(k!=2){
        aux=nr%10;
        nr=nr/10;
        x=nr;
        while (x>0){
            x=x/2;
            if (aux==x%10){
                printf("Numarul este %d", aux);
                k=2;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but this only works for one-digit numbers, because I'm multiplying by 10. If I want to support larger numbers, I could multiply by something bigger, but then `nr` gets too big.

So: how can I support numbers greater than 10?

Comment: Try sorting the array first

Comment: "Find a number that occurs twice in an array" There is no array in your code.

Comment: "I am not allowed to use vectors". OP perhaps means "array" as the English definition - a succession of numbers.

Comment: Are you allowed to use arrays?

Comment: If I understand correctly you are using a single integer as storage for several single-digit numbers, using the decimal places for each number. That is inventive but, as you notice, provides only space for up to 9 numbers. You should probably use arrays instead. You can use malloc to allocate space, or simply define a really large array if you cannot know how many numbers in advance.

Comment: If you can't use vectors or arrays, you'll need to store all the input values somewhere.   A (temporary) file comes to mind.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider He's not allowed to use an array.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Nine numbers because it's a 32-bit value?

Comment: Is there a maximum size of the input numbers? If they're less than the number of bits an integer, you can use an integer as a bit map.

Comment: Another thing is: If you want the readers (which includes you later in time) to understand the program you should give your variables speaking names. If you use a variable as a boolean value (like k) make it a boolean. Avoid numeric constants with special meanings (like 2 for "exit loop"). If you must use numeric values use named constants or enums with properly named members.

Comment: @Barmar Well, you can always define 100 variables.... I thought from C++ that he cannot use `std::vector`. If he cannot use arrays he should say "array", native speaker or not ;-).

Comment: Also don't harbor the illusion that you can store more numbers in a float just because the value range is larger ;-).

Comment: The bitmap idea can handle numbers 1 to 64 (possibly 1 to 128 on some machines).

Comment: Ask yourself this. You have a set of arbitrary numbers. What quatity can you compute that depends on the set of the numbers themselves but not on their order?

Comment: Define randomness please - is it any number out of n numbers or numbers between 1 and n+1 for n numbers?

Comment: Why do you necessarily need to store each digit in an integer ? you could append it in a string  and can be traversed by str.charAt(index) rather than integer operation like x%10 and nr/10. while storing as a string, you could store large numbers, which will solve your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood how i should do it. It was simple from the beggining, but thought it the hard way. 
If i have to enter numbers in the [1, n] interval, and there are n+1 numbers, the sum of them is n(n+1)/2 + the number that repeats. 
The word “random” killed my brain.
The number that repeats (it’s only one by the request of my teacher) equals to sum, which u do in a loop when u read the numbers, and then substract the sum of numbers from 1 to n. 
Thanks everyone for responses, if my answer is not clear, here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i, n, sum, nr, rep, k;
    k=0;
    sum=0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &nr);
        if (nr>n){
            k=1;
            break;
        }
        sum = sum + nr;
    }
    if (k==1){
        printf("Introduceti doar numere in intervalul 1, %d \n", n);
    } else{
    rep = sum - (n*(n+1))/2;
    printf("Numarul %d se repeta\n", rep);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in O(n) without extra space or counter.
you could modify the visited number to negative. while traversing if number is negative, then the number is duplicate.

```
 void returnDuplicate(int[] arr)
 {
   int n = arr.length;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    if(arr[arr[i]-1]>0)
    {
      arr[arr[i]-1]= -arr[arr[i]-1];
    }
    else 
    {
     print arr[i];
     return;
    }
  }
}
```

in your example,
if i=0,make this element as visited by reversing the sign;

```
arr[arr[0]-1] = -arr[arr[0]-1];

arr[0]=-1;

if i = 1, arr[1] =-2;

if i = 2 , arr[2]=-3;

if i = 3 , arr[arr[3]-1] which will be arr[2] which is  already negative, so this the duplicate element
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, which i didn't know! Thank you very much for it, but unfortunately i am not allowed to use arrays. But anyway, new information! Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You ill need an array of size specified by the user and fill it:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int a[n];

for (i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &a[n]);
}
```

and now you need to loop over the array:

- take the first element
- check for all following elements if it exists
- if yes, you are done
- if no, take the next element, etcetera.

As this sounds like homework, I don't give you this looping. It should be easy to write that in C.

Comment: No arrays should be used...i knew how to do it this way, but thanks!

Comment: Your proposed solution is extremely inefficient in terms of time and space, and would rightfully earn you a failure mark. You are supposed ti find an O(1) space, O(N) time solution.

Comment: @n.m. i red it wrong and i have edited the post with the answer. Anyway, i couldn't use vectors(arrays) because the teacher said so, no vectors. That's why i came with that inefficient solution..